# My local fonts are not working on AndroidOS with React Native (expo)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fonts, expo

I have a problem connected with using a custom font for Android OS with React Native. I am using expo.

```
import HelveticaNeuel55 from './assets/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTARMW05-55Rm.ttf';
import HelveticaNeuel65 from './assets/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTARMW05-65Md.ttf';
import HelveticaNeuel75 from './assets/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTARMW05-75Bd.ttf';
import HelveticaNeuel85 from './assets/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTARMW05-85Hv.ttf';
import SFProDisplayBold from './assets/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Bold.otf';
import SFProDisplayHeavy from './assets/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Heavy.otf';
import SFProRoundedBold from './assets/fonts/FontsFree-Net-SF-Pro-Rounded-Bold.ttf';
import SFProRoundedHeavy from './assets/fonts/FontsFree-Net-SF-Pro-Rounded-Heavy.ttf';

const fetchFonts = () => Font.loadAsync({
  'helvetica-neuel-55': HelveticaNeuel55,
  'helvetica-neuel-65': HelveticaNeuel65,
  'helvetica-neuel-75': HelveticaNeuel75,
  'helvetica-neuel-85': HelveticaNeuel85,
  'sf-pro-display-bold': SFProDisplayBold,
  'sf-pro-display-heavy': SFProDisplayHeavy,
  'sf-pro-rounded-bold': SFProRoundedBold,
  'sf-pro-rounded-heavy': SFProRoundedHeavy,
});
```

With this snippet I load my fonts, I have tried to name my object's keys with the same name as my font file name is, but it did not help.

And I am using my font with the code below.

```
smBold: {
        fontFamily: 'helvetica-neuel-75',
        fontStyle: 'normal',
        fontSize: scale(12),
        lineHeight: scale(16),
      },
```

These are my all dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.1.61",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.3",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3"
  },
```

And this is implementation of fetchFonts() function

```
if (!dataLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setDataLoaded(true)}
        onError={() => setDataLoaded(true)}
      />
    );
  }
```

Note that fonts are working fine in IOS, it does not work only on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
const fetchFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    "helvetica-neuel-55": HelveticaNeuel55,
    "helvetica-neuel-65": HelveticaNeuel65,
    "helvetica-neuel-75": HelveticaNeuel75,
    "helvetica-neuel-85": HelveticaNeuel85,
    "sf-pro-display-bold": SFProDisplayBold,
    "sf-pro-display-heavy": SFProDisplayHeavy,
    "sf-pro-rounded-bold": SFProRoundedBold,
    "sf-pro-rounded-heavy": SFProRoundedHeavy,
  });
```

Comment: That did not help me (